# Delete function in Django not working

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to create a delete function for my Workout model.
This is the model:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    workoutID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()   
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def delete(self):
        return reverse("delete_workout", kwargs = {'workout_id': self.workoutID})
```

Next I have the view:

```
def delete_workout(request, workout_id):
    workout = get_object_or_404(Workout, workoutID = workout_id)
    print(workout)
    if request.user != workout.created_by:
        return HttpResponse('Not ur workout')
    else:
        workout.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This is the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<workout_id>\d+)/delete/$', views.delete_workout, name='delete_workout'),
```

And finally the html:

```
<a href='{{ instance.delete }}'>
    <button>Delete Workout</button> 
</a>
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console, which is why I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to use the class based views (`DeleteView`) and read the documentation for the models. Your method `delete` in `Workout` is a big mess and total antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding delete method of the class just for getting the delete url. You will get the url by url function in the template like `{% url delete_workout instance.workoutID %}`. So remove the delete function from the model change your html href url. Leave the view and url as the same. No issues there

class should be

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    workoutID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()   
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And your html should be

```
<a href='{% url delete_workout instance.workoutID %}'>
    <button>Delete Workout</button> 
</a>
```

**NOTE:** django model itself adds id for each table, so you dont have to specify it as you did `workoutID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`. 
By default each model will have a id field just like `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

If you consider removing the workoutID then the model becomes

```
class Workout(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
        description = models.TextField()   
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the html will be

```
<a href='{% url delete_workout instance.id %}'>
    <button>Delete Workout</button> 
</a>
```

Comment: Very good point about the primary key. I didn't notice it at first sight. Many beginners reinvent the wheel when using frameworks, which defeats the purpose of using a framework.

Comment: ya, absolutely @cezar

Answer (score 0):

Django has all the tools for you under the hood. Don't reinvent the wheel. You can refactor and simplify your code.

First remove the method `delete` in `Workout`.

Second, replace your function-based-view with a class-based-view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import Http404

from .models import Workout

class WorkoutDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Workout
    success_url = reverse_lazy('delete_workout')

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        if obj.created_by != self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

A workout can be deleted only by its author. In `success_url` you specify the target where the user should be redirected after deleting.

Just adapt slightly your `urls.py` (pay attention to the emphasised part):

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.WorkoutDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_workout'),
```

EDIT:
You can name your views as you please, however it would be better to follow already well established conventions. Thus the names for the class based views should be `workout-list`, `workout-detail`, `workout-create`, `workout-update` and `workout-delete`.